# I want to modify the user interface of android for my device, is this possible if the OEM didnt provide the source code?

Tags: themes

The device is running android pie and i know that my build version is PPR1.180610.011 and its already currently running AOSP, however its the ALPS variation (which i think is mediatek's version (closed source)  of AOSP where they just augment the telephony based apps so it works with their HALs, while the android UI remains vanilla).
I want to modify the theming/ui parts of android (which im sure most of it resides in (system\system\framework\framework-res.apk) as shown in https://prnt.sc/vfn6r3

However as mentioned above there are some proprietary binaries shown here https://prnt.sc/vfn85h

1. Is it possible to build AOSP for my device (after making my desired theming enhancements) and then just migrate the proprietary binaries into their correct directories?
2. Or should i be looking at decompiling the framework-res.apk and recompiling it and then repacking the system img file?

P.S the bootloader is unlocked and i already have access to the unpacked partition img files

p.s installing xposed or any other theme modifying software is not an option as i dont have a custom recovery such as TWRP